# code lost after copying symfony / phpstorm / git folder

Tags: git, symfony, version-control, phpstorm

I have just made a copy of my symfony2 project from mydir/myproject to mydir/myotherproject.
I am using phpstorm and git for version control.

I don't know what is the cause of that but it reverted my code to my last git commit 13h ago so I've lost all I've done in the meantime.
If I click "show history" in phpstorm, I have nothing following my last commit. I kept however my database changes so I'm sure I'm not crazy ;-)

Why ? How can I retrieve what I had before ?

Comment: Whoa, must say it happened few times to me. Nothing critical, merely 10-20 lines of changeset. It always stoke me as it had something to do with autocomplete action (Ctrl+Space), but it was so rare that I ignored it. Same as with you, no history - nothing.

Comment: in my case it might be related to running php composer.phar something in the new folder with phpstorm still using parameters from the old folder... anyway, 12h of my live lost, I'll commit more often from now on!

Comment: *"If I click "show history" in phpstorm, I have nothing"* Is it Local History you have tried or some another history?

Comment: I have tried local history and checked my git rep. both are sync on my previous commit. anyway, I rewrote everything now, I'll just be more careful when changing something big